# NodeMCU - Are all GND connctions born equal?

Tags: voltage-regulator, ground, 5v, 3.3v, nodemcu

I'm designing a PCB which is based on NodeMCU board in its core.

On NodeMCU there are some GND pins, most of them are to serve digital outputs/inputs, or external sensors which operate on 3.3V.

Vin pin on the NodeMCU can get higher voltage (5+) which goes through a voltage regulator into the rest of the board.

My question:
When planning the connections to GND - should or shouldn't I bridge the different GND pins - between the 3.3V circuits and the 'outer' 5V input the comes before the voltage regulator?

Many thanks!

Comment: But some are more equal than others...

Comment: ... connect them all together, that will give the return currents the shortest path back to the source possible. I think if you continuity test the board you will find they are all connected internally anyway.

Comment: Really only the manufacturer can answer that.  Typically you would connect all grounds, though it may be less critical for a *module* than it would be for a bare IC where it is typically an *absolute requirement*.

Comment: Thanks everyone for looking into it and for the ideas. That's actually what I'm looking for - the 'official' answer the I can count on. I'll try to check continuenty of all my groudns later today and update myself. Manufacturer info can also be helpful. and last thing: I think this is a fundemental issue and question. Maybe if more of the viewers of it would 'upvote' for it - we would have more attention and better information will come here... :-) Again, Thanks to everyone who is trying to help.

Comment: draw a simple block diagram or share the schematics. in general yes. GND from 5 V will be connected to GND of all the components.